# Display kde-connect indicator in gnome top-bar

Tags: gnome, kde, indicator

I've got kde-connect installed in Gnome 14.04. This is syncing fine with my mobile so it's all working ok. 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vikoadi/ppa` 
`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get install indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect` 
I just want to add the indicator to my tray. I had kubuntu installed previously and it was possible to right click on an icon and send files to my phone and view charging status etc. 
Is there a way to get this icon to display permanently? 
I'm sure I've missed something simple.

Thanks